# which process would be the best to use in this situation

Tags: c, multithreading, ipc, process

I am trying to create two applications. One application should take inputs from user like name, address, phone number and send that information to the other application to store it. This should also be capable of reading the stored address information from the other application.
My assumptions for this:
I am planning to use system() process in application1 to create application2.
For communication between these processes, shared memory as IPC.
Can anyone suggest me whether this is the correct way for this task or is there any best and easy approach for this task.

Thank you.

Comment: Try a database. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Could you explain a little more clearly why you need two applications instead of one?

Comment: application1: It has to take the inputs(like name, address, phone number) and save them in application2. It should be capable of displaying results which are saved in application2.     application2: It must be capable of modifying the results saved into it.  For this task which process(system(), fork, exec) will be best suited for creating two applications. And for communication between processes which IPC will be easy and suite. thank you Luke and pmg

Comment: That is only restating the requirement, without any reason given.  If this is homework please tag it as such, and clarify what is required of the solution.  If it's not homework, I'd vote for pmg's database suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at google protocol buffers if you are looking for communication between processes in python , java or c++.

It is clean and elegant and works across files and sockets.

You can communicate using sockets between the two processes.